# Package versioning clashes in Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

Forgive me if this is a FAQ but I'm a bit puzzled about how to get around this problem properly.

I recently downloaded the package [TagSoup](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup-0.12.2) which installed fine with the latest version *0.12.2*

Then I installed the package [download-curl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/download-curl-0.1.3) which installed fine with the latest version. What I failed to realise was, download-curl depends on TagSoup with a version =< 0.11, so as part of the installation process Cabal downloaded an older version of TagSoup too.

This is a problem because I want to use both libraries (the latest version of TagSoup AND download-curl) - and when you do for some reason GHCI gets in a bit of a mess.

My question is, is there a way of specifying versions in your import statements, i.e.

```
import Text.Html.TagSoup-0.12.2
```

or is this a no go? I'm thinking not.

The only way I got around this was to download the download-curl source, modify the `.cabal` file to use TagSoup-0.12.2 and reinstalled the package with my little "hack" in place which works as I would expect it to - but I don't think this is the solution

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That is the solution.  Also, be sure to e-mail the maintainer of the package with the old build dep with a kind note (don, in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally one specifies the required version in the `.cabal` file.  There is an extension syntax for specific package imports ([`-XPackageImports`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#package-imports)) but it's usually better to let Cabal deal.

That said, yes, if you need to use both then you enter the dark realm of diamond dependencies.  Yours is pretty much the only solution available currently.  `-XPackageImports` is *not* a good idea here, as trying to use two versions of the same library in the same program probably won't link and almost certainly will dump core at runtime if it *does* manage to link without duplicate symbols.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, thanks for the tips too on the GHC extension, but as you say this probably wouldn't work in my case. Manually editing the cabal file and upping the version locally will have to suffice for now.