# How to import a specific version of a module

Tags: haskell, module, version, cabal

I have a project where I want to use `readCreateProcess` (I need the ability to portably pass a command to the default shell with input and read its output).

However, this function was only added in process-1.2.3 and several other packages I use (all newest versions) require `process <=1.2`.

I was wondering if I could import `readCreateProcess` from the newer package while still using the other packages.

I am using ghc/cabal for building and testing, if that is at all relevant.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526353/package-versioning-clashes-in-cabal) (if not duplicate).

Comment: You may think reimplementing `readCreateProcess` yourself is painful; you may think updating your dependencies to work with `process-1.2.3` is painful; but those are mere hangnails -- sharp, one-time pains that end quickly and never resurface -- compared to the appendicitis of having two versions of the same package in your dependency tree -- a random, unpredictable time-bomb that completely incapacitates you at the worst possible moment.

Comment: @Daniel I realize the risks, but I was thinking I could import and re-export it from a small module solely used for that purpose. I also do not need to use it in conjunction with other functions, I'm effectively using it as a black box string in, string out function.

Comment: Is there any complexity in your use case preventing you from using plain `readProcess`?

Comment: @zakyggapps yes. I need to pass user input, which is a shell command. If there is a portable unescaping function, I can use that instead.

Comment: @DanielWagner updating dependencies is almost impossible, I have a lot of packages that require the old process.

Unless you mean manual rebuilding.

Comment: @zakyggaps It probably makes more sense to suggest using `createProcess` as the replacement for `readCreateProcess` than it does to suggest using `readProcess` as the replacement.

Comment: @k_g Out of curiosity, which packages are requiring `process <= 1.2`? `process-1.2` was released in 2013! Additionally, I find your claim that it is "almost impossible" to update the dependencies strange; the API has been pretty stable, so I would expect that in almost all cases the fix is changing just one character in the appropriate cabal file.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for asking all those questions, I figured out how to fix the problem myself (see answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the fastest thing would be to fork `process-1.4`. I then renamed the package `processnew` and all the files within `System.ProcessNew` and `System.CmdNew`.

I then set it up as a submodule.

I then installed this package, added `processnew >= 1.4` to my `.cabal`, and imported `System.ProcessNew(readCreateProcess, shell)`.